# New to front end - Trying to solve submit button to add users in a table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need some help with a mini project in React - I am using TypeScript by the way.

I am making a list of users and a form to manually add a user in the list.
Note that I am borrowing fake users from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

The problem is that I can’t make the form button work properly. I am missing something and I don’t really know what! I’ve spent like three days on this, searched everything with no luck.

Please, excuse coding mistakes you might see, that's because I am learning!

For now I am trying to make it work and then I will take care of the code!

To whoever want to help me, thank you very much in advance!

Here is my code:

1. App component.
2. Form component.

```
import axios, { CanceledError } from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import UserForm from "./components/UserForm";

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

const App = () => {

 const [users, setUsers] = useState <User[]> ([]);
 const [error, setError] = useState('');
 const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();

  setLoading(true);
  axios
    .get <User[]> ('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {signal: controller.signal})
    .then((response) => {
      setUsers(response.data)
      setLoading(false);})
    .catch(error => {
      if (error instanceof CanceledError) return;
      setError(error.message)
      setLoading(false);})

  return () => controller.abort();
 }, [])

const deleteUser = ( user:User ) => {
  const originalUsers = [...users];
  setUsers(users.filter(u => u.id !== user.id ));
  axios
    .delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + user.id)
    .catch(error => {
      setError(error.message)
      setUsers(originalUsers)
    })
}

const addUser = (newUser:User) => {
  setUsers( [...users, {...newUser, id: users.length + 1} ] )
  axios
    .post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/', newUser)
    .then(response => setUsers([response.data, ...users]))
}


  return (<>

    <div className="mb-5">
    <UserForm onSubmit={addUser} />
    </div>


    {error && <p className="text-danger">{error}</p>}
    {isLoading && <div className="spinner-border"></div>}
    <table className="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <tr key={user.id}>
            <td>{user.id}</td>
            <td>{user.name}</td>
            <td>{user.email}</td>
            <td>{user.phone}</td>
            <td className="d-flex justify-content-center">
              <button
                className="btn btn-outline-danger rounded-0"
                onClick={() => deleteUser(user)}>Delete
              </button>
            </td> 
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </>);
};

export default App;
```

---

```
import { z } from 'zod'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';


const schema = z.object({
    id: z.number(),
    name: z.string().min(2, {message: 'Name should be at least 2 characters long'}),
    email: z.string().email(),
    phone: z.string().min(1, {message: 'Mobile Phone is required'})
})

type UserData = z.infer <typeof schema>

interface Props {
    onSubmit: (data:UserData) => void;
}

const UserForm = ( {onSubmit}:Props ) => {
    const { register, handleSubmit, reset, formState: {errors} } = useForm <UserData> ( {resolver: zodResolver(schema)} );
    
  return (<>
  <h1 className="display-6">Add a new contact.</h1>

    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => {
        onSubmit(data)
        reset()
    })}>


    <div className="mb-3">
        <input {...register('name')} id="name" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
        {errors.name && <p className='text-danger'>{errors.name.message}</p>}
    </div>

    <div className="mb-3">
        <input {...register('email')} id="email" type="email" className="form-control" placeholder="Email" />
        {errors.email && <p className='text-danger'>{errors.email.message}</p>}
    </div>

    <div className="mb-3">
        <input {...register('phone')} id="phone" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Mobile Phone" />
        {errors.phone && <p className='text-danger'>{errors.phone.message}</p>}
    </div>

    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0">Add contact</button>
    </form>
    </>)
}

export default UserForm
```

Comment: What exactly error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you have taken your Id as number but as you didn't give default value so It's consider it to undefined as initial time, so It's not validate your form actually

Try to make optional that field in your schema like below and try to submit your form again

```
id: z.number().optional(),
```

Comment: Whoever you are, I really THANK YOU for this!!! People helping me motivates me so much to move forward. Problem solved so fast with your help Krunal, thank you mate! 
I am now able to add people in the list but everyone has the same id and I am getting the "Encountered two children with the same key" error. New problem welcomed! :D

Comment: Always welcome, much appreciated :)

Comment: hahah, for that second problem, you can generate random id and give it to form as default value

Comment: Thank you for this idea! I don't really know how to implement that currently but I will brainstorm for some time and I hope I will find a solution! 
I am thinking of making a service with a function that generates random numbers outside of the component, then import it in somehow.

Comment: Hey, I just found out that this can't be implemented with the fake backend I am using, I really liked to go further but I've learned my big lesson with the form! Thanks again!